# Twoway binding crashes when I change datacontext

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, telerik

I am using twoway binding to dynamically change the color of one of my user controls and to set the initial selected color. It's structured as the following (way simplified):

```
<RadGridView x:Name="T" ItemsSource="{Binding storage, Mode=OneWay}">
    <GridViewColumn>
        <GridViewColumn.Template>
            <ColorPicker SelectedColor="{Binding Color, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        </...>
    </...>
</...>
```

And the associated C# code:

```
void func(object sender) {
    this.DataContext = sender;
}
```

I am getting a nullpointer exception when I try to change the DataContext of the GridView IF AND ONLY IF the GridView has elements in it. Is there a way to get around changing the source of a gridview that has twoway bindings?

Best,
Jin

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the third party control, you would need to talk to their support.

Comment: Telerik has all kinds of bugs.... I'm constantly coding workarounds for their controls >.< Their support forums are pretty good at helping out though if you provide some code samples so they can reproduce the problem.

Comment: I posted on Telerik's GridView support forum. Thanks guys.